# Convergence of a serie depending on an exponent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which $k>0$ is $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {1}{n+n^k})$ convergent.
I tried to prove convergence with the Ration test but it hasn't really worked.

 
by the P-test and comparison test I found that:

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {1}{n+n^k}) < \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {1}{n^k}) $

So that the majorant  $\frac {1}{n^k}$ is convergent for k>1,
therefore the condition for the convergence of the serie is fullfilled if k>1.

 
Is that correct?

Comment: The idea is correct, but the solution is incomplete - you want to determine what happens for $0 <k < 1$. There may be some $k < 1$ for which the series still converges. But using the $p$-test and comparison test like you did here will give you the answer to that question easily.

Comment: I know that the majorant is in this intervall 0<k<1 divergent, is that explanation enough?

Comment: Well, that depends on what your teacher wants of you. If he wants to see a proof for everything then probably not. But the methods you've used so far will work for $0 < k \leq 1$ with some easy modifications.

Comment: Yes he wants to see a proof, but I thought the fact that I have proved the p-test for another exercice,would make it possible, that I could use this.Do you have a suggestion for an other proof?Perhaps the integral test?

Comment: I do, but judging by your work so far I think you're more than capable of doing it by yourself. Just use the comparison test; since you're trying to prove divergence now, find a divergent series smaller than this series in question for $0 < k \leq 1$.

Comment: I don't know, the problem is that I have to hand this exercise in in half an hour...1/n^(2k)?

Comment: Well, I guess the half-hour is long past...for $0 < k \leq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n^k \leq n$ so $\frac{1}{n+n^k} \geq \frac{1}{2n}$, and $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ is a divergent series.

Comment: Yes, it is...but thank you for the help.